# Changing brightness under Unity completely hangs the system

Tags: 12.04, unity, brightness

I have a Dell latop and Ubuntu 12.04. The system will completely hang when I try to adjust the brightness either through the function buttons or through the system's brightness manager module. This hangs the system beyond the REISUB trick, I have to manually shut it down and I've had hard drive warnings because of this.

Brightness adjustment works flawlessly with `KDE`, so the issue is with the Unity shell.

What can I do about this? Should I just report a bug or is there something I should try first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known [kernel bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1007765) . A workaround to your problem is explained in comment #71.

1. Open the file /etc/defult/grub as root: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Change the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `"quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"`
3. Update the grub `sudo update-grub`
4. And reboot `sudo reboot`

Comment: Not working in Ubuntu 13.10 :(